# cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am using Android Dagger2 but I am getting the error below.

My AppModule class is:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    @Provides
    public DownloadFilePresenterImp provideDownloadfilePresenterImp(DownloadFileView downloadFileView) {
        return new DownloadFilePresenterImp(downloadFileView);
    }
}
```

My AppComponent interface is:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(DownloadFileView target);
}
```

My DaggerInject class

```
public class DaggerInjector {
    private static AppComponent mAppComponent = DaggerAppComponent
            .builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule())
            .build();

    public static AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        return mAppComponent;
    }
}
```

I am trying to inject into my Fragment (DownloadFileView)

```
@Inject DownloadFilePresenterImp mDownloadFilePresenterImp;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.download_file_view, container, false);
   /* Initialize presenter */
   DaggerInjector.getAppComponent().inject(DownloadFileView.this);


   /* Use mDownloadFilePresenterImp here */       
   return view;
}
```

And my DownloadFilePresenterImp constructor part

```
public class DownloadFilePresenterImp implements DownloadFilePresenterContact {
    public DownloadFilePresenterImp(DownloadFileView downloadFileView) {
        mDownloadFileContract = downloadFileView;
    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Error:(17, 10) error: com.sunsystem.downloadfilechatapp.downloader.DownloadFileView cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method. This type supports members injection but cannot be implicitly provided.
com.sunsystem.downloadfilechatapp.downloader.DownloadFileView is injected at
com.sunsystem.downloadfilechatapp.downloader.dagger.AppModule.provideDownloadfilePresenterImp(downloadFileView)
com.sunsystem.downloadfilechatapp.downloader.DownloadFilePresenterImp is injected at
com.sunsystem.downloadfilechatapp.downloader.DownloadFileView.mDownloadFilePresenterImp
com.sunsystem.downloadfilechatapp.downloader.DownloadFileView is injected at
com.sunsystem.downloadfilechatapp.downloader.dagger.AppComponent.inject(target)
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok...this should work

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    @Provides
    public DownloadFilePresenterImp provideDownloadfilePresenterImp() {
        return new DownloadFilePresenterImp();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class DownloadFilePresenterImp implements DownloadFilePresenterContact {

    private WeakReference<DownloadFileView> weak;

    public DownloadFilePresenterImp() {

    }

    public void setDownloadFileView(DownloadFileView view) {
        weak = new WeakReference<>(view);
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        if (weak != null) {
            DownloadFileView view = weak.get();
            if (view != null) {
                [...]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, all objects provided by the graph (the component) must be built with objects belonging or built by the graph itself. So I removed the `DownloadFilePresenterImp(DownloadFileView downloadFileView)` constructor that is going to cause a leak and replaced it with a setter that creates a WeakReference to the View.

**EDIT**

If you want to inject an object that you build at runtime, the only way to go is to pass that object to the AppComponent. In your case it could be:

*AppComponent.java*

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {

    void inject(DownloadFileView target);
}
```

*AppModule.java*

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    private final DownloadFileView downloadFileView;

    public AppModule(DownloadFileView downloadFileView) {
        this.downloadFileView = downloadFileView;
    }

    @Provides
    public DownloadFilePresenterImp provideDownloadfilePresenterImp() {
        return new DownloadFilePresenterImp(downloadFileView);
    }
}
```

*DownloadFilePresenterImp.java*

```
public class DownloadFilePresenterImp {

    private final DownloadFileView downloadFileView;

    public DownloadFilePresenterImp(DownloadFileView downloadFileView) {
        this.downloadFileView = downloadFileView;
    }
}
```

*DownloadFileView.java*

```
public class DownloadFileView extends Fragment {

    private AppComponent mAppComponent;

    @Inject
    DownloadFilePresenterImp impl;


    public DownloadFileView() {
        // Required empty public constructor
        mAppComponent = DaggerAppComponent
                .builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .build();
        mAppComponent.inject(this);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_download_file_view, container, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have already tried that solution. However, I am interested how I can use DI in my original question. I want to inject the DownloadFilePresenterImp with the argument of my fragment `DownloadFileView`

Comment: @ant2009 is it what you want now?

Answer (score 39):

The error just states that dagger doesn't have a way to provide said dependency. You will have to add it to your component in some way—and since it is a `Fragment`—you will have to use a `@Module`.

I am assuming that your `AppComponent` is created by your `Application` on start. Your `AppComponent` has a lifecycle that is longer than both your activities and fragments lifecycles are. It is therefore reasonable, that it does not know how to provide an activity, or a fragment in your case.

1. Your `DownloadFilePresenterImp` depends on your `DownloadFileView`.
2. You want to inject `DownloadFilePresenterImp` into your `DownloadFileView`
3. To inject the view and presenter you are using your `AppComponent` which knows nothing about the activity, and obviously nothing about the fragment. It has a different scope and lifecycle.

To not further cause confusion I will be talking about fragments, since their and the activities lifecycle are what you have to keep in mind. You can just use `DownloadFileView` with the module, but those long names would get confusing.

---

To *provide* a fragment or activity you *have* to use a module. e.g.

```
@Module FragmentModule {
    Fragment mFragment;
    FragmentModule(Fragment fragment) { mFragment = fragment; }

    @Provides Fragment provideFragment() { return mFragment; }

    // here you could also provide your view implementation...
    @Provides DownloadFileView provideDownloadFileView() {
        return (DownloadFileView) mFragment;
    }
}
```

Since this module should only live along with fragments lifecycle, you *have* to use either subcomponents, or components with a dependency on your `AppComponent`.

```
@Component(dependencies=AppComponent.class, modules=FragmentModule.class)
interface FragmentComponent {
    // inject your fragment
    void inject(DownloadFileView fragment);
}
```

In your fragment you'd have to properly create your component...

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.download_file_view, container, false);

   // properly create a component that knows about the fragment
   DaggerFragmentComponent.builder()
           .appComponent(DaggerInjector.getAppComponent())
           .fragmentModule(new FragmentModule(this))
           .build()
           .inject(DownloadFileView.this);

   return view;
}
```

Also, I **highly recommend** having a look at and using **constructor injection**

```
public class DownloadFilePresenterImp implements DownloadFilePresenterContact {

    @Inject
    public DownloadFilePresenterImp(DownloadFileView downloadFileView) {
        mDownloadFileContract = downloadFileView;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can move the `provideDownloadfilePresenterImp(View)` method to the `FragmentModule` to have the same effect if you like redundant code.

Done.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I had a presenter class in Kotlin, while using Dagger2. I forgot
`@Inject constructor`
as the constructor of the presenter.

Comment: Yes same here. This helped.

Comment: Oh my god. Thanks !! Even if the ViewModel is empty with no dependencies, we have to use `@Inject constructor` too!!

Comment: I have done that too.

Answer (score 4):

### The dagger errors was not very useful

In my case, I was using a mismatching version between my main `:app` module and other modules. Make sure you're using the right versions and that they are the same between modules.

As a permanent fix, in my android level `build.gradle`, I have the following:

```
buildscript {
    ext.dagger_version = "2.30.1"
}
```

and all my modules `build.gradle` files refer to the same version:

```
    // Dependency Injection
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
```

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend you to checkout this complete implementation of dragger :
https://github.com/Spentas/securechat/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/spentas/javad/securechat/app/AppComponent.java

Or follow following:

In your AppModule:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
public DownloadFilePresenterImp  provideDownloadfilePresenterImp(DownloadFileView downloadFileView) {
    return new DownloadFilePresenterImp(downloadFileView);
}
```

your AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
void inject(DownloadFileView target);
}
```

then you need to initialize your dagger in your Application Class :

```
public class App extends Application {
private AppComponent component;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mContext = this;
    component = DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(new AppModule(this)).build();

}
 public AppComponent getComponent(){
        return component;
    }
```

In wherever u want to use:

```
((App) App.getContext()).getComponent().inject(this);
```

Comment: I tried but did not work for me. When I use DownloadFileView interface  as void inject(DownloadFileView target) I get error can not provide without an Inject constructor or from an Provider-annotated.  When I pass activity that implements that view interface like void inject(DownloadFileViewActivity target) It compile but through dependency through null exception.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was that another component had an unused inject method with the same class as input parameter. Removed that inject method and it compiled.